# returning identity value in Visual Studio (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, winforms, identity

I have a project in Visual Studio where I need to use two tables, Bill and bill detail.

Bill has the primary key `billNumber` which I made with identity. And bill detail has the `billNumber` as a foreign key.

I need help. How can I know the last id which was created? Visual Studio doesn't recognize `top(1)` or other methods.

The tables are like this:

```
bill                                       bill detail

billNumer   idClient  amount               billNumber product quantity price
```

Comment: What is you current code to insert the Bill record? Do you use some ORM (Entity Framework, Dapper)? Please add more context to your question to avoid closure for lacking of clarity

Comment: `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` maybe?

Comment: A search would have yielded plenty of solutions. What about those solutions didn't work, or what about them didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following sql query to find the last id from the table.

```
SELECT billNumer FROM Bill WHERE billNumer = (SELECT MAX(billNumer) FROM Bill)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Seems rather convoluted? Doesn't `select max(BillNumber) from Bill` to the job? And there are much better ways to return the last ID created. FYI we prefer text to images on this site.